# Different result with Query builder and the processing 'extract by expression'

Tags: qgis, sql, query, qgis-3

I have a attribute table (xlsx sheet imported with the plugin 'spreadsheet layer'). For example, it contain only 15 lines

[image]

I have filtred the data with this request that return 6 lines (correct result) :

> "VALID" != '70' AND "MILIEU"  IN ( 'Entrées de grotte' , 'Grottes et
>   cavernes obscures'  , 'Cavité artificielle avec influences humaines' )
>   AND  "STRUCTURE" NOT IN ('tunnel','égoûts, canalisation')

[image]
[image]

Now, if I try to extact data with the same request in the processing modeler, I don't obtain the same result. All data with a NULL value in the field 'Structure' have been filtered. Any idea?

I don't understand why the first code works with the query and not with the extract processing?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your expression:

```
OR "STRUCTURE" = NULL
```

So your expression would look like:

```
"VALID" != '70' AND
"MILIEU" IN ('Entrées de grotte', 'Grottes et cavernes obscures', 'Cavité artificielle avec influences humaines') AND 
("STRUCTURE" NOT IN ('tunnel','égoûts, canalisation') OR 
"STRUCTURE" IS NULL)
```

---

It seems *NULL* values are not taken into account when using the `IN` operator.

Comment: Thank @Joseph for your reply! Unfortunately, this only works partially.
with the example, it return me 7 lines ('Cavités art.[..]', NULL, 70).
By following your example, I could make a complete query with the 'OR', but in my case, I have to filter an excel file on many fields and the query becomes very long. I don't understand why it works with the query and not with the extract processing.

Comment: @Christophe - Try `"STRUCTURE" = NULL` instead. I guess it's the way the processing tool is scripted.

Comment: With "STRUCTURE" = NULL (instean 'IS NULL') it return me only 2 lines. All data with a NULL value have been filtered

Comment: Your solution works with parentheses and IS : "VALID" != '70' 
AND "MILIEU"  IN ( 'Entrées de grotte' , 'Grottes et cavernes obscures'  , 'Cavité artificielle avec influences humaines' ) 
AND  ("STRUCTURE" NOT IN ('tunnel','égoûts, canalisation') OR "STRUCTURE" IS NULL)

Comment: @Christophe - Nice one! Glad you got it to work for your example :)